# Move object when touched on object

Tags: ios, objective-c

If you touch a specific object and move your finger, then the object follows your finger. When you touch the screen but **not** the object, then nothing happens.

Here's my code :

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint myPoint = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];
    _plaatje.center = CGPointMake(myPoint.x, myPoint.y);
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: _plaatje is the dutch translation for image.

Comment: For the total viewcontroller.m code:

http://pastebin.com/rU9HiCEj

Comment: @[http://stackoverflow.com/users/3529214/user3529214] use pan Gesture Recognizer and add that object which you want to mjove into it.

Comment: _plaatje is an UIImageView

Comment: More errors :(

Property "X" not found on UITouch
Property "Y" not found on UITouch
Property "Size" not found on UIImageView

Comment: Initializing 'CGPoint *' (aka 'struct CGPoint *') with an expression of incompatible type 'CGPoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint')

and...

Property 'size' not found on object of type 'UIImageView *'

Sorry, but i am a just 14yo apple developer from holland :)

Comment: Edited. I always forget about small errors)))

Comment: And _plaatje is an UIImageView

Comment: IT WORKS!!! THNK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that `_plaatje` is `SKNode`

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
CGPoint mytouch = [[[event allTouches] anyObject]locationInView:self.view];
if((myTouch.x>_plaatje.center.x-(_plaatje.frame.size.width)/2)&&(myTouch.x<_plaatje.center.x+(_plaatje.frame.size.width)/2)&&(myTouch.y>_plaatje.center.y-(_plaatje.size.frame.height)/2)&&(myTouch.y<_plaatje.center.y+(_plaatje.frame.size.height)/2))
{
_plaatje.center = [mytouch locationInView:self.view];
}
}
```

Comment: Weird, i am getting a lots of errors. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I have updated my code. Maybe it is more "useful" now.